# Get Random Nested arrays of objects and v-for

Tags: vue.js

I am working on simple vuejs example projects.

Basically, I am trying to display set of data in a loop. But I can't print the random name array from the nested object in vue 2.

It prints as a full array like { "name": "check1.1" }  I want to print them separately like Name, Chcek1.1 ... etc

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#sample',
  data: {
    private: {
      folders : [{
          name : 'folder1',
          checks : [
            { "name" : 'check1.1' },
            { "name2" : 'check1.2' },
            { "name4" : 'check1.1' },
            { "abcd" : 'check1.2' },
          ]
        },
        {
          name : 'folder2',
          checks : [
            { "name" : 'check1.1' },
            { "name2" : 'check1.2'},
            { "abcs" : 'check1.1' },
            { "abcd" : 'check1.2' },
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>


<div id="sample">
  
  <h1>current result: </h1>
  <div v-if = "private.folders!=null" v-for="folder in private.folders">
  {{folder.name}}
      <div v-for="check in folder.checks">
          {{check}} 
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>expected result: </h1>

<ul>
  <li>folder1
    <ul>
      <li>name</li>
      <li>check1.1</li>
      </ul>
    
    ---
    
    <ul>
      <li>name2</li>
      <li>check1.1</li>
      </ul>
    
      
    ---
    
    <ul>
      <li>name3</li>
      <li>check1.1</li>
      </ul>
    
    
  </li>
  
  <li>folder2
    <ul>
      <li>name</li>
      <li>check1.1</li>
      </ul>
    
    ---
    
    <ul>
      <li>name2</li>
      <li>check1.1</li>
      </ul>
    
      
    ---
    
    <ul>
      <li>name3</li>
      <li>check1.1</li>
      </ul>
    
    
  </li>
  
  
</ul>
```

The outer loop works just fine but inside checks[] I can't get them as I expected.

Comment: It looks like everything is displaying as expected, what do you mean "it does not load anything"? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Not sure what you're doing wrong. But your code looks OK. Please have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/52sy5nts/). Is your script executed?

Comment: Hi, under folder1 it display as "{ "name": "check1.1" }" but i want to display name & chcek1.1 separately, same as name2 and others. Please chcek here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XevMWo